# Remove purple colour from GDM on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gdm, customization, 21.10

I have removed the Ubuntu purple colour from gdm with some command I don't remember in the past and it returned after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10.

I tried: `sudo update-alternatives --config gdm3.css` to no avail. The command returns "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gdm3.css".

Any suggestions?

Comment: I want to replace the GDM background colour with the standard grey GDM one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run the below command to select the available two files.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gdm-theme.gresource
```

Example:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gdm-theme.gresource 
There are 2 choices for the alternative gdm-theme.gresource (providing /usr/share/gnome-shell/gdm-theme.gresource).

  Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        auto mode
  1            /usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource              10        manual mode
* 2            /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource   15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

Purple One (the default one)
[image]

Gray One (one of the option available by default)
[image]

Comment: This only changes the login screen. It does not affect the purple splash bg that shows up just after you login.

Comment: @LSM-DAT_Linux there is a different approach to hide that milli seconds splash.

Comment: so what is it??

Comment: What is your Ubuntu Version? https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3037/good-bye-gdm-flick/

Comment: 21.10 - the issue is I need to do it in the command line for a custom ISO release.

Comment: Custom iso using cubic? End user installs it or uses as live iso

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want the end user to see it. Not in the live ISO, or anywhere. I want it gone. It's like a bad smell, just impossible to remove.

Comment: Using Cubic you can install any extension and make it enabled.

Comment: "This extension is incompatible with the current GNOME version" great, just great

Comment: I need to review it for Ubuntu 21.10 which may take more time. Edit metadata.json file from the extension files and add shell version 40 to the array [3.36]

Comment: it installs but does not activate automatically

Comment: Doesn't work even when activated.