# How to change ubuntu Lock screen to gnome lock screen?

Tags: boot, gnome, lock-screen

I want to change to gnome lock screen on start up because I don't like orange lock screen.

### Ubuntu Version

```py
21.10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove purple colour from GDM on Ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369841/remove-purple-colour-from-gdm-on-ubuntu-21-10)